# probability of default for Kolomogorov backward equation

Tags: black-scholes-pde, default

suppose
$$dA = \mu Adt + \sigma AdX.$$
is a geometric Brownian motion. One says that the Probability  $P(A,t)$ of $A$ reashing the critical level $K(t)$ before maturity:
$$\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial t} + \dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2A^2\dfrac{\partial^2 P}{\partial A^2}+\mu \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial A} = 0$$
I know this  is the `Kolomogorov backward equation` for transition density, but why this is true for probability function here? It seems we should replace CDF by PDF i.e replace $P$ by $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial x}$?

Actually the background is the probability of default, `Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance Volumne II` Page641 39.2.2
[image]

Comment: @Quantuple  sorry, here is $P(A\geq  K(t))$

Comment: Ah, now this makes more sense :) Then you could equivalently see that equation as the pricing PDE for a digital option.

Comment: the price PDE of digital option is same as the black-schole equation, how does a probability become this form?

Comment: Because your $P(a, t)$ is actually $Q(A_T > K \mid A_t = a) = \Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}[ 1\{ A_T > K \} \mid A_t = a]$. Which can be seen as the undiscounted price of a digital option. The discounted price should verify the usual pricing PDE since it should emerge as a $\Bbb{Q}$-martingale (Feynman-Kac formula).

Comment: If I did not interpret your $P(A,t)$ correctly would you please insert a copy of the page 641 you refer to since I do not own that book.

Comment: @Quantuple  see the update

Comment: I think the probability is defined by  $P (\tau <T\mid \mathcal {F}_t) $. Then the PDE holds automatically given the martinaglity.

Comment: @Gordon sorry, could you show some detail of `martinaglity`. This problem has puzzled me for a long time in many section. I really want to see the proof of result.

Comment: $P(\tau<T \mid \mathcal{F}_t) = E(1_{\tau<T}\mid \mathcal{F}_t) $ is a martingale.